# Is this MOLD under laundry room sink?

Tags: mold, water-damage

Just purchased a home and under the laundry room sink I found the below picture:

Is it MOLD?

If it is MOLD, do I need to get a professional here to remedy the situation or do I scoop it up with a shovel and then dump bleach on and around the area?

I haven't disturbed the area... yet.

[image: mold under laundry sink?]

Comment: Further to an answer given, it is mold and with fungus and was caused by a leaky faucet and/pipe (fitting). You will need to remove that piece entirely and replace it with a new one. Simply cleaning it will not be enough. Don't go putting a piece on top of it.

Comment: ...because it will come back.

Comment: Hey @Fred-ii-  feel free to add that info to the end of my answer by editing it!

Comment: @HMSCelestia It has been done. I see a *"This edit will be visible only to you until it is peer reviewed."* message after I edited it. I for one have done some work in this field before (non paying) and know what that's about and what is involved when it comes to materials that must be replaced. It's a dirty job, but someone's got to do it ;-)

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure how the peer review system works, but if I get a notification I'll accept it!

Comment: @HMSCelestia I believe the peer system was put in place for low rep members when editing. I've been through that before on StackOverflow when I was low rep. I gained the editor's badge a long time ago, so I can edit posts on StackOverflow without going through that again. It's a good way to keep the riff raff out and avoid spamming, etc. If I happen to do future edits on this Exchange, and prove that I am worthy of edits, then I most likely will be granted that privilege then. *Cheers* P.s.: I'm not just "a coder" lol I have gotten my hands dirty and know my way around a shop/garage too. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It may be mold, but even if it were, you hardly need a professional to help you get rid of it, just spray down the area with bleach and wait a few minutes (not too many though, as that can damage the finish further) to let it do its thing, then (while wearing proper protection, ie rubber gloves, etc) wipe up the area using a cloth and warm water. Then continue cleaning the rest of the cabinet with the disinfectant of your choice. However, its important to keep in mind that this isn't a permanent fix.

The discoloration (brown) that you see is simple water damage, and unfortunately I don't believe there's an easy way to fix that.

The most important thing though is to identify the original source of the moisture and ensure that you keep the cabinet dry in the future to prevent additional buildup of mold and mildew.

Taken from [Fred's comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/96903/is-this-mold-under-laundry-room-sink?noredirect=1#comment141977_96903):

It is mold and with fungus and was caused by a leaky faucet and/pipe (fitting).

You will need to remove that piece entirely and replace it with a new one.

Simply cleaning it will not be enough. Don't go putting a piece on top of it, because it will come back.

Comment: This answer contradicts itself? Shouldn't this be two separate responses (clean vs replace)?

Comment: Sorry, let me fix that.